# Calling a function while ignoring the returned value

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

There is a function in this code whose task is to increment some variables, then to return a value calculated from these variables.

In this case I need to call this function to increment the variables but I don't need any value returned.
Is there a way to tell this function: "do your job but don't return anything"?

Or is it OK to just ignore the value returned?

Thanks

Note: I'm working on a code I didn't wrote myself, so please don't ask why things are like this and not like that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to ignore the returned value. Doing so is a common occurrence in many languages.

For example, the splice() method will add or remove elements from an array. When you remove elements this method returns the elements that were removed. You are free to do something with those returned elements or just ignore them.